# React HighCharts cannot use marker-clusters

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I am new to highcharts. I have looked into the marker-clusters implementation using vanilla javascript as shown in examples [here](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/marker-clusters).

The vanilla javascript implementation works as expected but porting the solution in react is not working.

I understand that additional functionality in highcharts needs to be imported from specific modules but I cannot find the relevant module **marker-clusters** inside my **node_modules** folder.

I have a demo codesandbox replicating the issue [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-greider-1dn9i?file=/src/Map.js)

Basically, the demos in highcharts sample use

`<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/marker-clusters.js"></script>`

for the clustering behaviour but I am not able to do the same in react.
Any help is much appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The marker clusters feature is avalivable in Highcharts since v8.0.0. You are using version 7.2.1.

You need to upgrade your Highcharts, import and initialize `marker-clusters` module:

```
import markerClusters from "highcharts/modules/marker-clusters";
markerClusters(Highcharts);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-bash-y44sh?file=/src/HighMapsWrapper.js

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/marker-clusters

**Changelog:** https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/#highcharts-v8.0.0

Comment: Thanks. I did notice that and updated my local implementation. But I was unaware of the initialization part especially in react. This helped a lot.